# Using data-direction with dynamically loaded pages

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, dynamic

I'm trying to load dynamic pages with jQuery, following this [example](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dynamic-samples/sample-reuse-page.html#category-items?category=animals).

(EDIT): Updated the code to provide a better view of the context

Here is a code sample

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageSample">
    <div data-role="header">title</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-direction='reverse'>Home</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    // Generate dynamic content of targeted pages...
    $.mobile.changePage($(page), {
        transition:"slide",
        dataUrl:url,
        reverse:reverse
    });
});
```

The back button may be dynamically generated or not (such as this snippet). In both cases, it does not work reverse, as `changePage` is triggered through `pagebeforechange`.
Therefore, I inserted a `reverse` variable in `changePage()` options.

I can't find a way to retrieve the data-direction value of the clicked item.
I tried this just before `changePage()`:

```
reverse = false;
$('a[data-direction="reverse"]').on("click", function(){
    reverse = true;
});
```

But the `reverse` value is not updated in `changePage()`. I guess both codes run synchronously.
Is there a way to update the `reverse` value in `changePage()` ?

Comment: I dont understand, why do you use changePage when your button has defined href?

Comment: `data-rel="back"` instead of `data-direction="reverse"`, as the last one is meant to reverse the transition effect only, where `data-rel=back` works like a back button.

Comment: Some buttons have a defined href, but not all of them...

Comment: @Gajotres what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final update**

As per our discussion and your example http://jsfiddle.net/Iris/UZBhx/21/

Change this

```
$('a').on("click", function()
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", 'a', function()
```

**Another update**

Binding the `$.mobile.changePage` to `pagebeforechange` triggers all your code twice. Thus you lose the value of `reverse` or it gets neglected when the command executes the first time.

Try binding it to `pagebeforehide` as below.

```
$(document).bind( 'pagebeforehide', '[data-role="page"]#PageId', function( e, data ) {

// Generate dynamic content of targeted pages...

  $.mobile.changePage($(page), {
   transition:"slide",
   dataUrl:url,
   reverse:reverse
  });
});
```

**Update**

To use reverse effect on specific buttons, you can follow this method.

First, assign a class for buttons with reverse effect, e.g. `ui-reverse` and add the below script.

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-role='button'].ui-reverse', function() {
 $.mobile.changePage( url, {
  transition:"slide",
  reverse: true, 
  dataUrl:url
 });  
});
```

**"*Back*" button links - Jquery Mobile**

```
data-direction="reverse"
```

Is meant to simply run the backwards version of the transition that will run on that page change, while data-rel="back" makes the link functionally equivalent to the browser's back button and all the standard back button logic applies.

```
data-rel="back"
```

This will mimic the back button, going back one history entry and ignoring the anchor's default href.

Adding `data-direction="reverse"` to a link with `data-rel="back"` will not reverse the reversed page transition and produce the "normal" version of the transition.

In your case, you want to reverse transition, use the below code.

```
$.mobile.changePage($(page), {
 transition:"slide",
 reverse: true, // this will reverse the affect of the transition used in the page.
 dataUrl:url
});
```

[Read more about it here.](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to use changePage() as content and buttons are dynamically generated. However, I don't want all buttons to perform a reverse transition. How can I modify changePage options according to the attributes of the clicked button ?

Comment: @Yako my pleasure, please check my updated answer. I hope I have been of help.

Comment: Thanks again. My problem is not solved yet, but your answer allowed me to update the question, and make it more precise.

Comment: I finally got it an other way thanks to your comments. I had difficulties to handle pagebeforehide to get the targeted url.

Comment: Can you post your complete code on pasteit or any other site?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26196/discussion-between-yako-and-omarnew2php)